# Efficient enemy avoidance for pathfinding with fewer enemies

Tags: python, path-finding

I am currently working on a 2D top down rogue-like game using Python. The map is a dungeon containing many open rectangular rooms [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eucXp.png), each with around 2-4 enemies inside. I am currently looking to implement a path-finding system where the enemies will move around each other and attempt to swarm the player.

So far, I have implemented an A* algorithm that does allow the enemies to navigate and swarm the player in this way. However, my approach is causing very low frame rates: generally around 15 FPS but it will go as low as under 1 FPS when an enemy has no path to the player. I feel it is very inefficient, since path-finding is being done for every enemy on each frame. Currently, other enemies are seen as obstacles for the A* algorithm, and the only optimization is that an enemy will move directly towards the player if there are no obstacles in its way. Here's the code:

```
import heapq
#...
FLOOR = 1
#...

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        #...
        self.pathfindingGranularity = 5

    # Slope and line intersection functions are based on: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/864704/Python-Line-Intersection-for-Pygame
    def lineInRect(self, start, end, r):
        if start in r and end in r: return True

        if self.segmentIntersect(start, end, r.origin, Point(r.x + r.width, r.y)) is not None: return True
        if self.segmentIntersect(start, end, Point(r.x, r.y + r.height), Point(r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height)) is not None: return True
        if self.segmentIntersect(start, end, r.origin, Point(r.x, r.y + r.height)) is not None: return True
        if self.segmentIntersect(start, end, Point(r.x + r.width, r.y), Point(r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height)) is not None: return True

        return False

    def slope(self, p1, p2):
        if p2.x - p1.x == 0: return 1e10
        return (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x)

    def yIntercept(self, slope, p1):
        return p1.y - slope * p1.x

    def lineIntersect(self, start1, end1, start2, end2):
        min_allowed = 1e-5
        big_value = 1e10
        m1 = self.slope(start1, end1)
        b1 = self.yIntercept(m1, start1)
        m2 = self.slope(start2, end2)
        b2 = self.yIntercept(m2, start2)
        if abs(m1 - m2) < min_allowed: x = big_value if (b2 - b1 >= 0) else -big_value
        else: x = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)
        y = m1 * x + b1
        return Point(x, y)

    def segmentIntersect(self, start1, end1, start2, end2):
        intersection = self.lineIntersect(start1, end1, start2, end2)

        def approx(f):
            return round(f * 10000) / 10000

        if not approx(start1.x) <= approx(intersection.x) <= approx(end1.x):
            if not approx(end1.x) <= approx(intersection.x) <= approx(start1.x):
                return None

        if not approx(start2.x) <= approx(intersection.x) <= approx(end2.x):
            if not approx(end2.x) <= approx(intersection.x) <= approx(start2.x):
                return None

        if not approx(start1.y) <= approx(intersection.y) <= approx(end1.y):
            if not approx(end1.y) <= approx(intersection.y) <= approx(start1.y):
                return None

        if not approx(start2.y) <= approx(intersection.y) <= approx(end2.y):
            if not approx(end2.y) <= approx(intersection.y) <= approx(start2.y):
                return None

        return intersection

class Enemy (Entity):
    def update(self, game):
        #...

        if not self.getRect().intersects(game.player.getRect()) and self.canMove():
            self.generatePath(game)

            if self.path:
                # Move towards player

        elif self.canMove():
            # Hurt the player

    #...

    def generatePath(self, game):
        if not self.lineOccupied(Point(self.x, self.y), game.player.getCenterpoint(), game):
            self.path = [game.player.getCenterpoint()]
            return

        frontier = PriorityQueue()
        start = Point(self.x, self.y)
        frontier.put(start, 0)
        came_from = {}
        came_from[start] = None

        done = False
        while not frontier.empty():
            current = frontier.get()

            if Rect(current.x + self.hitbox.x, current.y + self.hitbox.y, self.hitbox.w, self.hitbox.h).intersects(game.player.getRect()):
                done = True
                break

            for next in self.findAdjacents(current, game):
                if self.lineOccupied(current, next, game): continue
                if next not in came_from:
                    priority = self.heuristic(next, game)
                    frontier.put(next, priority)
                    came_from[next] = current

        if not done:
            self.path.clear()
        else:
            p = [current]
            while came_from[p[-1]] is not None:
                p.append(came_from[p[-1]])

            self.path = p[::-1][1:]

            i = 0

    def findAdjacents(self, currentPoint, game):
        d = 1 / game.pathfindingGranularity
        for x in (currentPoint.x - d, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.x + d):
            for y in (currentPoint.y - d, currentPoint.y, currentPoint.y + d):
                if x == currentPoint.x and y == currentPoint.y: continue
                elif self.canWalkAtCoords(x, y, game):
                    yield Point(x, y)

    def canWalkAtCoords(self, x, y, game):
        for nx in (x, x + self.hitbox.w):
            for ny in (y, y + self.hitbox.h):
                if game.blockAt(nx, ny) != FLOOR:
                    return False
        return True

    def lineOccupied(self, start, end, game):
        for e in self.room.enemies:
            if e is self:
                continue
            for xo in (self.hitbox.x, self.hitbox.x + self.hitbox.w):
                for yo in (self.hitbox.y, self.hitbox.y + self.hitbox.h):
                    if game.lineInRect(start + Point(xo, yo), end + Point(xo, yo), e.getRect()):
                        return True

        return False
```

I feel like there should be a much more efficient solution to this, especially seeing as the room is rectangular and there are no extra walls or obstacles that the enemies need to move around, but so far my searches for a solution have come up empty-handed. Are there some optimizations I could make to increase the performance of the program? Or if not, is there a better pathfinding method I should look into? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An easy way would be to only perform the path finding algorithm at specific intervals (e.g. 60 frames).

Comment: Path finding isn't really necessary (when there are no fixed obstacles). Simply move one step in the direction of the player. If the way is blocked by another enemy, and the distance to the player is large, then simply wait till the other enemy moves. It's only when the enemies are all clustered around the player that you need pathfinding, but in that case, you only need path finding within a very small area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to have you path finding start from your character and fan out using a breadth-first-search (with some adjustment for slopes). Every time you come across an enemy, you can compute its optimal path toward the player.

That way you only do one pass across the whole board rather than one for each enemy.

Let me know if you want more details.